# How to distinguish the difference between Market Profile according to Volume and Price?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, stock-valuation, money-market

Recently, I am concerned about using Market Profile in trading. There are two ways using Market Profile including either consideration of volume or change of price.

Generally speaking, if we consider each level of price, which changes during the 30-minute trading session, we can establish the graph of a normal distribution. On the other side, in terms of changing in price level, we can define each TPO-(a letter) for each level of price. These TPOs also form a graph of a normal distribution. However these two graphs are similar but not congruent.

I wonder why they are similar like that? I mean why do the changes in price link to volume? Do all of things about auction behavior that makes price moves up and down depend on volume?